# Getting following error An error occurred while installing json (1.8.1), and Bundler cannot continue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, xcode, bundler

I am trying to create a new rails app. But I am getting following error while running bundle install:

> An error occurred while installing json (1.8.1), and Bundler cannot continue.

I tried various options like `xcode-select --install`, `rm -rf test` as given in previously asked questions but without success.

Please help me in resolving this issue. I am stuck because of this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a problem with xcode if you are using MacOS X 10.8. You can try to solve a problem with this manual: http://robots.thoughtbot.com/the-hitchhikers-guide-to-riding-a-mountain-lion

Also, there can be a problem with superuser. Try to install json with sudo.

```
sudo gem install json -v '1.8.1'
```

Comment: I tried sudo gem install json -v '1.8.1' earlier and it didn't work. But now it worked. :) Thanks for your help.